# How can $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ at a maximum?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I can understand $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ being the case at an inflexion point: To the left of the inflexion point the gradient is increasing and to its right the gradient is decreasing (or vice versa), therefore the rate of change of the gradient is negative to the left and positive to the right (or vice versa) which means that the graph of the rate of change of gradient crosses the $x$-axis at the point of inflexion, i.e. $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$.

However, when I tried to apply this thinking to $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ at a maximum point it doesn't seem to make sense. Here is my attempt: For a maximum point with $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$, as we move from the left of the maximum point to the right, the gradient must first be decreasing, then stop decreasing at the maximum point (otherwise $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ doesn't hold), then continues to decrease past the maximum point.

The part where the gradient stops decreasing is what I don't understand: Surely a gradient can only stop decreasing at some point if the curve near that point is a horizontal line? (Otherwise it will be decreasing at every point in the locality of the point.) Does this mean that a maximum point satisfying $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is a horizontal line near the maximum point? I tried "seeing" this by using the fact that a graph becomes flatter at a point where there is a double root (which is the case for a maximum point with $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ since we also have $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ at that point), but flatter doesn't mean horizontal so this explanation doesn't seem to work either.

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: There seems to be a misunderstanding. I know that the second derivative at a maximum may not be zero; I am simply looking for an intuitive explanation of how it can become zero. In particular, I am trying to understand how (obviously in cases where $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ at a maximum, or a minimum, for that matter) the fact that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ is consistent with the graph only being horizontal at one point, namely the maximum. My intuition is telling me that for $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ to hold, the graph has to be "momentarily" horizontal rather than just horizontal at one point, i.e. it has to be a straight horizontal line *in the locality* of the maximum - but this isn't the case for e.g. $y=x^4$ and yet at the minimum $x=0$ we have $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$. How is this even possible - the graph does not stop and become "momentarily" horizontal at $x=0$ all of a sudden does it?

Comment: At a maximum, the second derivative does not need to be $0$. It can also be nonzero.

Comment: A side note: in this question we deal with functions of one real argument $x$ (a scalar). In this context the use of the term "gradient" is not justified. *Gradient* is a vector that can be viewed as a generalization of the 1st derivative when $x$ itself is a vector (i.e. when our $f(x)$ has more than one argument $x_1$, $x_2,\ldots$). Some misunderstandings might be cleared simply by rephrasing your thoughts without the terms like "gradient". Similarly, we'd better avoid the undefined term "momentarily horizontal".

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd derivative *may be* zero at a maximum point. Example:
$$
f(x)=-x^4 \quad\mbox{ at } x=0.
$$
The 2nd derivative *may also be* nonzero at a maximum. Example:
$$
f(x)=-x^2 \quad\mbox{ at } x=0.
$$
In a lot of practically important cases (e.g. in physics) it's nonzero.

Note that, in both examples above, the graph of $f(x)$ itself is a curve, and not a horizontal line. The *tangent to $f(x)$ graph at the maximum is horizontal* in both examples.

Comment: Thank you, but there seems to be a misunderstanding - please see my edit. In particular, I am trying to understand how (in cases where $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ at a maximum) the fact that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ is consistent with the graph only being horizontal at one point, namely the maximum. My intuition is telling me that for $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ to hold, the graph has to be "momentarily" horizontal rather than just horizontal at one point.

Comment: (1) Is "momentarily" different from "at one point"? How? (2) Consider the Taylor series expansion at the maximum point. The main difference is that the first nonzero term in this expansion is either $c(x-x_0)^2$ or some higher power, e.g, $c(x-x_0)^4$. Does this help?

Comment: I think so yes because $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ is horizontal at one point but not "momentarily" horizontal since $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\not= 0$. Sorry if that doesn't make sense but I hope you understand my problem. Thanks

Comment: I am afraid "momentarily horizontal" is not a well-defined term. To avoid such difficulties, we can just agree that in both examples the tangent (if it exists) is a horizontal line when $f(x)$ is at its maximum. Separately, there are also examples like $g(x)=-|x|$ where the tangent *does not exist* at the maximum.

Comment: I know you have already answered my question but I believe there was a misunderstanding. If you can answer this you will have helped me out immensely: For the graph $y=x^3$, explain intuitively (i.e. using the graph of the function) why $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ at $x=0$. For example, if the question was instead "for the graph $y=x^2$ explain intuitively why $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ at $x=0$", I would say: Because the tangent to the graph is horizontal at $x=0$, therefore $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ at that point. Unfortunately I can't formulate a similar (graph) explanation for the $y=x^4$ question.

Comment: Here is an intuitive (not very rigorous) procedure to find a maximum of a *smooth* $y=f(x)$. (The procedure will work for  $f(x)=-x^2$ and for $f(x)=-x^4$ but might not work for an arbitrary $f(x)$ graph.) Start with a horizontal line $y=1$, check that this line does not touch the $f(x)$ graph. Now *lower* the line gradually until the line touches $f(x)$. The touch happens when the line is lowered to the level $y=0$ (can you see why?) The touch happens at just one point, $x=0, f(x)=0$; at all other points $f(x)<0$. This works for $f(x)=-x^2$ as well as for $f(x)=-x^4$.

Comment: If this was helpful, can you please accept the answer? Thanks and Happy New Year!

Comment: Sorry but you still haven't answered my question. My last question was asking about the second derivative, your comment is about the first derivative.

Comment: Also, in my last comment about $y=x^3$ I was meant to say at the end "I can't formulate a similar (graph) explanation for why $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ at $x=0$ in the $y=x^3$ question".

Comment: $y=x^3$ changes from concave to convex at $x=0$ where 2nd derivative is zero. This is called an inflection point. The function $y=x^3$ has neither a minimum nor a maximum.